# For In on array of objects

Tags: javascript, oop, object, for-in-loop

I am working on a piece of code that prints out the contents of objects within an array. I have got it working by printing out each item of the object but was wondering if it is possible to do this with:

```
for(var property in array){
}
```

Here is a copy of the code I am currently using:

```
for(var i=0;i<app.members.length;i++){
            output.innerHTML += "<div class='member'><p><b>Id: </b>" + app.members[i].id + "</p><p><b>User: </b>" + app.members[i].user + "</p>" +
            "<p><b>Name: </b>" + app.members[i].name + "</p><p><b>Email: </b>" + app.members[i].email + 
            "</p><p><b>Age: </b>" + app.members[i].age + "</p></div>";
        };
```

Here is a copy of the for in attempt:

```
for(var property in app.members){
            output.innerHTML += ("<p><b>" + property + ":</b> " + app.members[property] + "</p>");
        };
```

The problem I get with the second is that it is returning the object not the attributes of said object.

Comment: You're doing it the right way in the working code - what are you hoping to improve with a `for in`?

Comment: `for...in` is a bad way of iterating arrays.

Comment: Cuts down on the amount of code that is being executed, I believe it does anyway. Also looks neater.

Comment: @Oriol -- Why is it a bad way?

Comment: @hudsond7 Because it also iterates on the objects prototype chain (inherited properties), which cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for in` is for iterating properties, so I suppose you could do:

```
for(var i=0; i < app.members.length; i++) {
    for (var prop in app.members[i]) {
        output.innerHTML += ("<p><b>" + prop + ":</b> " + app.members[i][prop] + "</p>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `app.members[i]`? Otherwise I don't see what this is doing that the OP isn't

Comment: Not exactly. Please look again.

Comment: Would this print out the attributes of the objects within the array? When running the for in it prints the objects, I am unclear as to how putting it within a for loop would help.

Comment: @JasonBaker -- Yeah - missed the `[i]`

Comment: @hudsond7 -- Please try again, I made an edit - missed an important part in the `for in`

Comment: @tymeJV -- Okay understand now, will test.

Comment: @MartinErnst -- Where?

Comment: @MartinErnst -- There is.

Answer (score 1):

With `for...in` you can iterate the properties of an object, but not the properties of all objects in an array.

You can try

```
var html = '';
for(var i=0; i<app.members.length; i++){
    html += "<div class='member'>";
    var member = app.members[i];
    for(var prop in member) if(member.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        html += "<p><b>" + prop + ":</b> " + member[prop] + "</p>";
    }
    html += "</div>";
}
output.innerHTML = html;
```

However, note that when you iterate using `for...in`, you can't assume any order. That means that each `app.members[i]` could be iterated in a different way, and you don't want that.

Therefore, I would use something like

```
var html = '',
    props = ['id', 'user', 'name', 'email', 'age'];
for(var i=0; i<app.members.length; i++){
    html += "<div class='member'>";
    for(var j=0; j<props.length; j++){
        html += "<p><b>" + props[j] + ":</b> " + app.members[i][props[j]] + "</p>";
    }
    html += "</div>";
}
output.innerHTML = html;
```

Also note DOM operations (like `innerHTML`) are slow, so avoid using them at each iteration if you can. Better use a variable, and update the DOM at the end.

Comment: Would your second example still be applicable if I am placing it into an already structured HTML document?

Comment: @hudsond7 Not sure "an already structured document" is, but I can't see why it should be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the hasOwnProperty method.

```
for(var property in app.members){
        if (app.members.hasOwnProperty(property))
            output.innerHTML += ("<p><b>" + property + ":</b> " + app.members[property] + "</p>");
    };
```

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Every object descended from Object inherits the hasOwnProperty method. This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the in operator, this method does not check down the object's prototype chain.